# Visual Studio Setup Project My Documents Path (similar to [ProgramFilesFolder])

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I would like to set a registry key to the user's documents folder. I was able to get the variable for [ProgramFilesFolder] to work successfully as a test and get a key with C:\Program Files...... Does anybody know what a similar variable would be for the documents folder that works in visual studio set up projects?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the one you want is [PersonalFolder] which is typically C:\Users\username\Documents.

Having said that, these are standard system locations and there is usually no need to store them on behalf of any programs because they are easily retrieved using (for example) Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles or Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments.